# Emacs: Using a major-mode's font-locking only for mmm-mode

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, emacs, elisp

I've got MMM-mode set up to edit .html.erb files, but indentation does not work in the ruby sections, and all the different electric behaviours of ruby-mode do the wrong thing.  I've changed this sub-mode from ruby-moode to fundamental-mode, and it works much better.

I want to still use ruby-mode's font-locking though, is this possible/easy?  Any hints on where to start.

Elisp is comfortable to me, but I don't have too much time right now to dig too deeply myself.  Hopefully someone will have a snippet?

Answer (score 0):

I see you haven't yet found an answer. Dunno whether it will be better for this, but you might consider using **[MuMaMo](http://www.emacswiki.org/cgi-bin/wiki/MuMaMo)** instead of MMM.

Answer (score 0):

To answer the question, you would define a major mode deriving from `fundamental-mode`, and in its body just copy the font-lock-related lines from the `ruby-mode` definition body, the ones setting `font-lock-` variables and also `syntax-propertize-function`. Naturally , you need to `(require 'ruby-mode)` somewhere.

But for `.html.erb` files I can now recommend using [mmm-erb](https://github.com/purcell/mmm-mode/blob/master/mmm-erb.el), which was not available when this question was asked.